# Centos 7 how to install php7.3 from official sources?

Tags: centos, software-installation, php

I am coming from the debian world and I struggle for a while now understand Centos and to install php7.3 on Centos 7.

Tutorials like this https://tecadmin.net/install-php7-on-centos7/ tell me to install some remi release. What is "Remi's RPM repository" and why is php7.3 not in the official package sources?

```
[root@centos7 ~]# uname -a
Linux centos7 3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Feb 1 14:54:57 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: The only "official" release of PHP 7 from RedHat/CentOS is offered through the [Software Collections repo](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/user/rhscl/), which can be added to a CentOS machine with `yum install centos-release-scl` from the `extras` repository.  This does not replace the system provided components, but side installs each different version with special environment variables to be able to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RHEL/CentOS intends to prioritize stable versions of packages before new versions of packages. This strategy backfires with PHP since the latest version in the repository is 5.4, [which is EOL](https://www.php.net/eol.php).

It's common practice to install a 3rd-party repository for PHP, however I would recommend [Webtatic](https://webtatic.com/) instead of Remi.

Comment: I second not installing Remi.

Comment: As I am totally new to Centos/RHL-Branch. Why not Remi? EDIT: Looked at Webtatic, they seem to only have 7.1 and 7.2, I need 7.3 by customer request

Comment: I prefer Webtatic because it has a wider variety of PHP modules right there in the repository. Remi doesn't have nearly as many. Some can still be installed through pear or pecl, but I've had far more trouble with that than just installing them from Webtatic's repository. I had forgotten that Webtatic still doesn't support PHP 7.3, so you will probably have to use Remi. Personally, I've just been using 7.2 when I'm on CentOS with the intention of installing 7.3 once Webtatic has it.

Answer (score 0):

While the version of php on RHEL and CentOS correspond to those that have been EOL'd upstream, they are continually checked for bugs and security fixes by the redhat team.  Similar to how/why RHEL7/CentOS7 is using kernel version 3.18, for example.  It's part of a long-term support strategy primarily focused on enterprise users.

With the advent of SoftwareCollections (`scl`), it is possible to make use of newer versions of php.  While scl is a part of a CentOS Special Interest Group (SIG), and therefore closer to the official CentOS project than third-party repos like remi, it does need to be installed and enabled.

To enable the SCL repositories, on CentOS7, simply run:

```
yum install centos-release-scl
```

That should install the repos and enable them as well.

By default, installing a php version from scl also pulls in another version of apache, i.e. `httpd-httpd24`.  However, it is perfectly fine to use the regular apache version with the scl-provided php.  See [this howto on centos wiki pages](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/php7) for a brief setup guide.

Assuming that you already have httpd installed and running, do the following to install php version 7.3, for example.

```
yum -y install rh-php73 rh-php73-php rh-php73-php-fpm
```

Create a config file in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/fmp.conf`, for example, with the following entries:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*.php)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html
Alias / /var/www/html/
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Then, enable and start the php-fpm service, and you should be good to go.

```
systemctl enable --now rh-php73-php-fpm.service
```